# What is the best approach for Timeout using Selenium using Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have run into a problem. My web page has a `DropDownList` control. Once the `DropDownList` value changes (by selecting a different value), the page refreshes and it renders the contents.

And then I have to use `Thread.Sleep(2000);` before it goes and `FindElement`.

**My question:** What is the best way to wait till the page loads?

I have so many instances of `Thread.Sleep(2000)` in my code that I am beginning to think this is not the best way to approach the problem.

Here is my code:

```
[TestInitialize()]
public void Setup()
{
    if (BaseIntegrationTest.browserType.Equals(BaseIntegrationTest.IE))
    {
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }
    else if (BaseIntegrationTest.browserType.Equals(BaseIntegrationTest.CHROME))
    {
        //driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    else if (BaseIntegrationTest.browserType.Equals(BaseIntegrationTest.FIREFOX))
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
}
```

And the second part:

```
[TestMethod]
public void testVerifyData()
{
    // ...................
    // ...................
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_NavigationControl1_lnke']")).Click();

    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    //select from the dropdownlist.
    IWebElement catagory = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Filter"));
    SelectElement selectCatagory = new SelectElement(catagory);
    selectCatagory.SelectByText("Employee");

    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    // ...................
    // ...................
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thread.Sleep() is a very discouraged way to implement your waits

This code is outlined on the selenium documentation http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement category = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
    {
        return d.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Filter"));
    });
```

That is an example of an explicit wait where selenium will not execute any actions until your element is found

An example of an implicit wait is:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement category = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Filter"));
```

In implicit waits the driver will wait for a given amount of time and poll the DOM for any elements that do not exist.

*EDIT*

```
public WaitForElement(string el_id)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    IWebElement category = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
    {
        return d.FindElement(By.Id(el_id));
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Greg, so i have to do for every id? or is there a way i can make more abstract?

Comment: Np, accept the answer if you like it XD. Just make it an object if you want to resue it then you can just feed the object an id as an argument or whatever and reuse it whenever you need. That is what I have done with all of my waits

Comment: just curious to know, should I be wrapping `WaitForElement` for all the Ids or just those Ids which will take time? or what is the best practice..

Comment: only the element's that you know will take time. So at the least by placing some kind of wait you are telling the machine to execute extra instructions which will take more time, which slow down your tests. If an element is found reliably with FindElement, then don't bother using a wait. But if the element is the first element you want to find after you've opened a new page or something then a wait will probably be necessary

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem by using WebDriverWait too.

But I set wait till the last element shown up (ex: the footer, the last item in the list).

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Id("footer")).Displayed);
```

or

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(d => d.FindElements(By.TagName("li")).Last().Displayed);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some cases where you do need to wait, in which case the Task.Delay method will provide more predictable results than Thread.Sleep

Task.Delay(1000).Wait(); // Wait 1 second

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the refresh caused by the interaction is something that Selenium can detect, then the following method will likely do what you need:

[waitForPageToLoad](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#waitForPageToLoad%28java.lang.String%29)

As far as I know, this method checks a state within the browser to see if the browser thinks it's loading something, and waits until this state is cleared. However, this ready state is sort of old - there are so many ways to dynamically load a page or part of a page that the ready state isn't always an accurate depiction of what's going on.

If you know what is going to change as a result of your action - that is, if you know that after you interact with the drop down list, specific UI elements will appear that were not on the page before - then  you would likely be better off waiting for those specific UI elements to appear. You could do this by writing a method that repeatedly checks for [isTextPresent](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#isTextPresent%28java.lang.String%29) and waits in small increments, until either a timeout is reached or the expected element appears. There are other "is X Present" methods that can be used in these methods, which you can find elsewhere in the Selenium Interface I linked to.

Comment: waitForPageToLoad is not an api in selenium 2

Comment: Whoops. I'm just jumping into Selenium again after a long absence. Got a lot to learn. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you want get html after page is loaded or timeout is expired:

```
using (var chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver())
        {
            chromeDriver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

            try
            {
                chromeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(link);
                return chromeDriver.PageSource;
            }
            catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
            {
                return chromeDriver.PageSource;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a custom function for my self, maybe it will be useful for someone:

```
 public static void waitForPageToBeLoaded(WebDriver driver, int time) {

     ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectation = new
     ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {     
         public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
             return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
            }
     };

     Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Long.valueOf(time)); 
     try {
         wait.until(expectation);
     } catch(Throwable error) {
         System.out.println(error);
         mainFunctions.reportFailure("[waitForPageToBeLoaded] Page load took longer than " + time/60 + " min.");
     }
 }  // waitForPageLoaded
```