# C# await Task.Delay Not working as intended with WinForms/Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, task, delay

I am doing a test with a website using Selenium and Winforms. 
i have to use Delays here and there quite often. 
i still can't understand what might be a problem. and i am not that good with whole " deadlock " thing but i checked few answers here and the code doesn't seem to a deadlock one.

so basically, this is the function `internal async Task HandleInput()`
the use of it is the loop through each line of a text file then enter it to a website.
the loop, every logic is in place correctly, and it was working until yesterday and today when i started VS and ran a check on the app, it just gets struck right on that line where the `await Task.Delay(1000);` is written.
on the other hand, Task.Delay(1000).Wait(); works fine.

This is how i call the Task Function from the main `HandleInput()` Function.

```
Logger.LogGenericText("starting process...");                    
                await SignInToSite(DriverChrome, Wait, id, pass);
```

here is the `SignInToSite()` Function:

Function Head: `public async Task SignInToSite(IWebDriver DriverChrome, WebDriverWait Wait, string id, string pass)`

```
try
        {
            Logger.LogGenericText("Acessing Login URL...");
            DriverChrome.Navigate().GoToUrl("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            await Task.Delay(1000); //entire program goes to standstill in here, UI isnt struck. 
            Logger.LogGenericText("Passing id and Password to respective fields...");
            Wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Name("username"))).SendKeys(steamId);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Name("password"))).SendKeys(pass);                
            Wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Id("UserLogin"))).Click();
            await Task.Delay(3000);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogGenericText(ex.ToString());
            return;
        }
```

I tried the compiled program on another PC, No fix.
would be glad if anyone could point me to the right direction.

Comment: Instead of using a Delay, just lookup for if the elements you need have loaded. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43203243/how-to-get-webdriver-to-wait-for-page-to-load-c-selenium-project

Answer (score 1):

Ok so, seems like it was some sort of deadlock or something. However, i managed to fix it by using `ConfigureAwait(false)` after every await statement.
i used the `ConfigureAwait Checker` From Nuget to get the things done fast.