# Trying to grab each Reddit title to decide what to click

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to get every title from every post into text form. Every text is contained in a h3 tag and I was trying to get the title that way to no avail.

Here is what I have so far.

```
 public void runBrowser()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/nintendoSwitch/";

       string finalText = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("h3")).Text;

        Console.WriteLine(final);
    }
```

I have tried using Xpath but also was met with no results. If anyone could help that would be great

Comment: What about using the [RSS feed](https://www.reddit.com/r/nintendoSwitch/.rss)?

Answer (score 0):

You page might not fully loaded yet when you try find an element. Please follow answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43203243/how-to-get-webdriver-to-wait-for-page-to-load-c-selenium-project) thread to wait for the text. Also that is possible that there are several h3 elements, and first one is empty, so find all `h3` elements on the page instead of first one.